# How to send email body and PDF attachment using PHP?

Tags: php, email, pdf

The script below can send pdf file as an attachment to Gmail and Outlook, but will not display in Yahoo mail. What's wrong with my code?

Secondly, when mail is sent, it doesn't carry along the message body apart from the pdf attachment itself. Any suggestion on how I can add message body with pdf attachment will be appreciated.

```
<?php
include("inc/conn2.php");

$customer_ID=$_GET['id'];
$invoice_ref_no=$_GET['ref'];

$query_sql= "SELECT * FROM add_biller_setup";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query_sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$biller_email_address= $row['email_address'];
$biller_email = str_replace(' ','',$biller_email_address); 


$customer_emails=$_POST['customer_emails'];
//$cust_emails=explode(',', $customer_emails);
foreach($customer_emails as $key => $email_value){

$to =$email_value;
$subject = "Customer Invoice Details";

$pdfdoc = $mpdf->Output('', 'S');

$fileatttype = "application/pdf";
$fileattname = "Invoice.pdf";
$mainMessage = "Please find the attachment included the mail.";


$headers .= 'From: ABS Motor LTD<billing@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: '.$biller_email.'' . "\r\n";

$semi_rand     = md5(time());
$mime_boundary .= "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
$headers      .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
  "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
  " boundary={$mime_boundary}";

  //$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" ;
  //$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
 // $headers .= "X-Priority: 1 (Highest)\n";
  //$headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\n";
  //$headers .= "Importance: High\n";

  $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
  "-{$mime_boundary}\n" .
  "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8\n" .
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
  $mainMessage. "\n\n";

$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));
$message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
  "Content-Type: {$fileatttype};\n" .
  " name={$fileattname}\n" .
  "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
  " filename={$fileattname}\n" .
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
$data . "\n\n" .
 "-{$mime_boundary}-\n";



// Send email
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
  $customer_ID=$_GET['id'];
    $invoice_ref_no=$_GET['ref'];
  $successMsg = 'Invoice has sent successfully.';
  echo '<p style="color:green; font-weight:600; font-size:1.5em;">'.$successMsg.'</p>';
  echo '<p style="color:black; font-size:1.2em;">Shortly you will be re-directed back to the invoice page.</p>';
 echo '<meta content="3;invoice_details?id='.$customer_ID.'&ref='.$invoice_ref_no.'" http-equiv="refresh" />';
}
else{
  $customer_ID=$_GET['id'];
    $invoice_ref_no=$_GET['ref'];
  $errorMsg = 'Some problem occurred, please try again.';
  echo '<p style="color:red; font-weight:600; font-size:1.5em;">'.$errorMsg.'</p>';
  echo '<p style="color:black; font-size:1.2em;">Shortly you will be re-directed back to the invoice page.</p>';
  echo '<meta content="3;invoice_details?id='.$customer_ID.'&ref='.$invoice_ref_no.'" http-equiv="refresh" />';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: I would suggest using a library that will handle the MIME stuff for you - see [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for your corrections, i didn't know that before now..

Answer (score 0):

kindly use phpmailer class library to get your desired output.

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer